# Echo a selected id from MySQL table

Tags: php, sql, mysql

I have this

```
    $sql = "SELECT id FROM table";

    $result = mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error());

    while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){

    echo $row['id'];

    }
```

This echo's all id's found in the table.

How can I choose to echo only a selected id.

Say the second id found on the table?

EDIT

I think I have confused people and myself aswell.

Let me try to explain again.

Using the above query I can echo all results found in the table with echo $row['id'];

However I do not want echo all results, just selected ones.

You guys have suggested I use limit or a Where clause.

If I do this I will be limited to just one record. This is not what I want.

I want to echo a selection of records.

Something likes this

echo $row['id'][5], $row['id'][6], $row['id'][6]

But obviously this is incorrect syntax and will not work but hopefully you get what I am trying to do.

Thanks

Comment: What about adding the selected Ids to SQL's `WHERE` clause?

Comment: What @Amil said. Also don't use `mysql_fetch_array` if you're not planning on using its numeric indeces. Use `mysql_fetch_assoc` instead.

Comment: why do you need "second id found"? what is your certain task, without those "say"?

Comment: I don't want to do that, I need select a list of id's and then store them individually. So I can you later in the script.

Comment: @JamJam - your question doesn't mention storing of ids to access later. Can you update your question with a little more detail?

Comment: @chris nor does it say that the other rows are not required..

Comment: "the second id found on the table" - when sorted to what criteria? Without sorting, the database is not guaranteed to return results in any particular order (it may be returning same results *now*, but insert a few rows, and the "unsorted order" might change).

Comment: nope, you are wrong. you aren't limited to just one record with LIMIT nor with WHERE clause. your question is still unclear, **what is your certain task?** what is your data, what is table structure, what is criteria to select ids? Why do you behave like a prisoner of war being questioned in the enemy headquarters, trying to hide every detail?

Comment: @jamjam I have updated my answer below.

Answer (score 1):

If you only want the second row then you could change your query to use offset and limit e.g.

```
SELECT id FROM table LIMIT 1, 1
```

You could also use a for loop instead of the while loop and then put in a conditional.

**UPDATE**

Just noticed comments above - you also need to sort the PHP bug by changing mysql_fetch_array to mysql_fetch_assoc.

**UPDATE 2**

Ok based on your update above you are looking to get all of the rows into an array which you can then iterate over.

You can just use mysql_fetch_array and then use $array[0]. For example:

```
$sql = "SELECT id FROM table";

$result = mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error());
$ids = array();
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
    $ids[] = $row[0];
}
```

Comment: Ok I will change mysql_fetch_array to mysql_fetch_assoc. But I don't want use that select. I need to select all id's from the table. And the have option to echo a specfied id later in the script.

Comment: mysql_fetch_array returns an array resulting from a single row, not from all rows

Comment: it still has no more sense than before. you guys love to ansver imaginagle, useless. nonsense questions. While in real these questions are dramatically different and being solver other methods - with LIMIT and WHERE clauses as it have been said already. You have no mercy for the poor OP who just can't phrase his question correctly, and you answer the question literally, without trying to think even a bit. And only your concern is reputation points. What a shame.

Comment: The OP does not want to use LIMIT so I dont really get your point to be honest.

Comment: he don't want it just out of ignorance - it's clearly stated, he says `limit will be limited to just one record.` while it's obviously wrong. Our duty is to help him understand the matter, not to follow his lame requests literally and mindless. What's so hard to understand here? Where y'all lost your common sense?

Answer (score 0):

From what I can gather from your questions you should not be selecting all records in the table if you wish to just use the Nth value, use:

```
SELECT id FROM table LIMIT N, 1
```

That will select the Nth value that was returned. Note: The first result is 0 so if you wish to get the second value the Nth value should be 1.

Answer (score -1):

[mysql_data_seek()](http://php.net/mysql_data_seek) let's you jump to a specific data-set(e.g. the 2.nd)

Example:

```
$sql = "SELECT id FROM table";
$result = mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error());

//get the 2nd id(counting starts at 0)
if(mysql_data_seek($result,1))
{
  $row=mysql_fetch_assoc($result);
  echo $row['id'];
}
```

**OR:**
use **[mysqli_result::fetch_all](http://php.net/manual/de/mysqli-result.fetch-all.php)**

It returns an array instead of a resultset, so you can handle it like an array and select single items directly (requires PHP5.3)

Comment: So which part of my answer forces a downvote? It's exactly what the OP is looking for(also after updating his question)